# Is there a usage pattern in Javascript to prevent the pitfall of 2 in [1,3,5] === true?

Tags: javascript

Some usage that I find a bit tricky is

```
2 in [1, 3, 5]

for (var i in [1, 3, 5]) { ... }

str = "hello";
for (var i in str) { ... }
```

the first one is `true` (I might have immediately said `2 in [1, 3, 5]` is `false`), and the second line loops through 0, 1, 2 instead of 1, 3, 5, and the last part loops through 0 to 4, instead of `'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'`.  Right now I am just using: whenever seeing `in` for array, or for-in loop for array, immediately think about index instead.  Otherwise, is there a way or usage pattern that we can use to avoid this pitfall?

Comment: Where is the pitfall? You mean because one gives a `boolean` and the other the property name?

Comment: in some language, 2 in [1,3,5] is false, because it checks whether 2 is in the array.  and for (i in [1,3,5]) will loop through 1,3,5 instead of 0,1,2

Comment: JavaScript has `.forEach()` to give you values instead of indices. `[1,3,5].forEach(function(item, i) { console.log(item, i); });`

Comment: Depending on the environment you're executing code in, you could use [`Proxy`s](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:proxies) to create your own `in` / `for in` semantics.

Comment: @user1689607 `.forEach` is for ECMA 5.1?

Comment: Yes, it was introduced in ECMAScript 5 and can be easily shimmed in ES3 environments. [Here's a compatibility shim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Compatibility), but use the second (long) one instead of the poor, non-compliant short one.

Comment: That shim will break (bad) code using `for(var i in array)` though

Comment: @ThiefMaster: That's a good thing. Bad code should break so it can be found and fixed.

Comment: Here's a proxy "solution": http://jsfiddle.net/fwBAc/. It works on Chrome with a flag set, though, so it's not practically useful.

Comment: FYI, with respect to "sparse arrays" as you mentioned below, `.forEach()` automatically skips over holes in the Array, so you wouldn't need any explicit tests. Same goes for the other iteration style methods on `Array.prototype`. http://jsfiddle.net/dqQwH/ And you also keep the proper numeric order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's called *"do not use `in` for arrays"*. It tests if an object has a certain key - so you cannot properly use it on arrays.

You also shouldn't use `for(var x in something)` unless you want to iterate over the properties of `something`.

To check if a value is contained in an array use `~arr.indexOf(value)` - or `arr.IndexOf(value) != -1` if you want it more verbose.

To iterate over the elements in an array use `for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)`

Comment: really?  so the general advice is not to use for-in loop for array?  because even the Javascript Definitive Guide talk about for-in loop for array...  http://books.google.com/books?id=6TAODdEIxrgC&lpg=PA147&ots=obbpJOQqTK&dq=sparse%20array%20definitive%20iterate%20array&pg=PA147#v=onepage&q=sparse%20array%20definitive%20iterate%20array&f=false but it immediately says to check using `hasOwnProperty`... so I guess using `for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)` is always cleaner?

Comment: @動靜能量: That book is giving you really bad advice. Find a better book.

Comment: now I think sometimes we do have to use `if (i in arr)`... unless there is another method, so we just have to be careful

Comment: another thing is that what if the program use a sparse array, then maybe it is more efficient to use for-in loop, because if we loop over using `i = 0; i < arr.length; i++`, then we can be checking for all those non-existence elements

Comment: @動靜能量: Sparse array is an edge case, and it would only make a difference if the Array is *very* sparse. It doesn't provide justification for using `for-in` on Arrays as standard practice.

Comment: `indexOf` is not supported in IE prior to version 9

Answer (score 1):

You can use `indexOf` method. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/azXqn/1/)

for Array

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4];
arr.indexOf(2); // will return index of item if exist other wise return -1;
```

for String

```
var str = 'Hello world';
str.indexOf('e')
console.log(str.indexOf('e'),str.indexOf('n'));
```

​

Comment: and I suppose we use `if (arr.indexOf(2)) != -1)` or `if (arr.indexOf(2) >= 0)` to check the existence, vs if in Ruby, `if (arr.indexOf(2))` is good enough because `0` is true in Ruby (just as a comparison)

Comment: Since 0 is valid index in JavaScript so 0 means element exist at first place in array. -1 if item does not exist in array. see the comment

Answer (score 1):

The `in` keyword is meant to be used with objects, like this (taken from the [MDN site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#in))

```
// Arrays
var trees = new Array("redwood", "bay", "cedar", "oak", "maple");
0 in trees;        // returns true
3 in trees;        // returns true
6 in trees;        // returns false
"bay" in trees;    // returns false (you must specify the index number,
                  // not the value at that index)
"length" in trees; // returns true (length is an Array property)

// Predefined objects
"PI" in Math;          // returns true
var myString = new String("coral");
"length" in myString;  // returns true

// Custom objects
var mycar = {make: "Honda", model: "Accord", year: 1998};
"make" in mycar;  // returns true
"model" in mycar; // returns true
```

An array can be thought of as an object. The array `['zero', 'one', 'two']` is like the object `{0: 'zero', 1: 'one', 2: 'two'}`

So if you write `for (i in ['zero', 'one', 'two'])` javascript will treat it as if you wrote `for (i in {0: 'zero', 1: 'one', 2: 'two'})`.

You can check if an object has a particular property value like this:

```
function isIn(val, obj) {
  for (var i in obj) if (obj[i] == val) return true;
  return false;
}

isIn('car', ['car', 'horse']) // returns true
```

If you're specifically checking an array and not just an arbitrary object, you can use the [`indexOf` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) which returns the index of its argument or -1 of the array does not contain the argument.

```
function isInArray(val, arr) {return arr.indexOf(val) > -1;}

isIn('car', ['car', 'horse']) // returns true
```